# Page refresh on submission of entry_form with the text "select" in it

Tags: forms, security

I'm using the exp:channel:entry_form to allow users to add content to my site. A nagging bug for quite some time has been that the page the entry form is submitted on just refreshes if the form contains the text "select", even in the form of a longer word like "selection". It's not always consistent, some forms do go through. I'm sure it's a sql security thing but this particular constraint is too tight. I haven't been able to figure out how to solve it (and I'm quite familiar with editing system files). I could detect it in JS and warn the user against using it but I feel this would be a poor mans patch. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [Safecracker](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html), where surely this bug does not exist. From the [docs for the Stand-Alone Entry Form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/entry_form.html):

> "Deprecated since version 2.1.5: This tag is deprecated in favor of SafeCracker and will be removed from future versions of ExpressionEngine. It is no longer supported."

Comment: We have a fairly customized EE site, lots of little hacks here and there. I know it's not great. Either way when I was updating this page I couldn't get safecracker to work properly....I don't remember why. I was hoping I could fix this in this version.

Comment: I tested safecracker again and it seems to integrate easier than I remember. I guess I'll go with this.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Safecracker has come a long way in recent point releases.